# Input Validation When Using a Rich Text Editor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for text entry. I have turned off input validation so the HTML created from CKEditor can be passed into the controller action. I am then showing the entered HTML on a web page.

I only have certain buttons on CKEditor enabled, but obviously someone could send whatever text they want down. I want to be able to show the HTML on the page after the user has entered it. How can I validate the input, but still be able to show the few things that are enabled in the editor?

So basically I want to sanitize everything except for a few key things like bold, italics, lists and links. This needs to be done server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [AntiXSS](http://antixss.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment would be a start. That removes any scripting from the HTML. What about the HTML though? Any HTML could be entered. Maybe that really isn't a concern, and only XSS is. I'm not too familiar with the best practices around this. I rarely have a need for users to input something that won't be encoded.

Comment: Well, the principal disadvantage of "safe" HTML is that it could be malformed. In which case, something like Tidy might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

See my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427649/check-for-script-in-asp-net-text-box/1427694#1427694) from similar question:

> I have found that replacing the angel
>   brackets with encoded angel brackets
>   solves most problems

Comment: How is that different than HTML encoding? The problem is, I don't want to convert the angle brackets. Basically, there is a certain set of HTML elements I want to allow to not be encoded. Things like bold, italics, links, and lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "whitelist" of sorts for the html tags you'd like to allow.  You could start by HTML encoding the whole thing. Then, replace a series of "allowed" sequences, such as:

```
"&lt;strong&gt;" and "&lt;/strong&gt;" back to "<strong>" and "</strong>"
"&lt;em&gt;" and "&lt;/em&gt;" back to "<em>" and "</em>"
"&lt;li&gt;" and "&lt;/li&gt;" back to ... etc. etc.
```

For things like the A tag, you could resort to a regular expression (since you'd want the href attribute to be allowed too). You would still want to be careful about XSS; someone else already recommended AntiXSS.

Sample Regexp to replace the A tags:

```
&lt;a href="([^"]+)"&gt;
```

Then replace as

```
<a href="$1">
```

Good luck!